# How to append HTML text input to table using pure javascript

Tags: javascript

I have two text input one for name and the other for date of birth.I have one Add button such that when i click the add button the name and date of birth should arrange in order in my table.The table heading are ORDER,USERNAME,BIRTHDAY and lastly the CONTROL which should be able to delete and and edit name. USING JAVASCRIPT.

Comment: Have you tried anything ?

Comment: have you made any efforts code-wise ?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like Jquery append() may be your best option.

It works in the following manner.

```
$( ".class" ).append("html / text to be appeneded");
$( "#id" ).append("html / text to be appeneded");
$( ".class" ).append(data);
$( "#id" ).append(data);
```

This is similar to Jquery html() but append simply adds on to a point where as html() overwrites what is there.

There is also attr() which allows you to add and modify attributes of a given html entity.

Here is a link to the documentation for append()
http://api.jquery.com/append/